# Django - Filter Queryset With Another Modal's Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have two modals: Group and GroupContents.

**GroupContents Modal:**

```
class GroupContents(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content= models.TextField(max_length=180)
```

**Group Modal:**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=80, default='')
    private= models.TextField(blank=False, default='0')
```

I want to filter my GroupContents queryset as releated Group object not private. I don't know how to solve that. I tried this but didn't work:

```
class GroupContentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = GroupContentsSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = GroupContents.objects.filter(self.group.secret=0)
        return queryset
```

I don't know how to approach. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
class GroupContentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = GroupContentsSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return GroupContents.objects.filter(group__private='0')
```

It looks however strange to use a `TextField`, and not a simple [**`BooleanField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `GroupContent` instead of <s>`GroupContents`</s>.